# What do all these Runners Lingo abbreviations like PR and HR mean?

Tags: running, terminology

In other running related question there is often made use of abbreviations like PB, PR, HR, VO2 etc.

I know what PB means (Personal Best), but what do the others mean and what other examples are there?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Technical Terms

- VO2 = VO2 Max, Maximum volume of oxygen (O2) that can be absorbed by the body
- LSD = Long Slow Distance run
- HR = Heart Rate
- HRMAX = Maximum Heart Rate, useful to get 60% and 85% values for training effect
- RHR = Resting Heart Rate

### Records

- OR = Olympic Record
- WR = World Record
- NR = National Record
- CR = Competition Record/Commonwealth record
- PR = Personal Record (Others might use PB for Personal Best)
- PW = Personal Worst
- DFL = Dead freaking last, a proud and honoured tradition.
- DNF = Did Not Finish
- DNS = Did not start
- DNQ = Did not qualify

Comment: In the USA, PR (Personal Record) is often used instead of PB.

Comment: PR = Personal Record

Comment: Ich bien eine Canadian.  (We used PB).

Comment: Might want to add the typical abbreviations used in competitions: PR/PB, CR (competition/championship), NR (national), OR (Olympic), WR (world) records.

Comment: @geoffc I am Swiss, we also use PB, although with german meaning ;-)

Comment: And the dreaded DNF = Did not finish.

Comment: @Ron i like to pretend DNF did not exist.  I prefer DFL to DNF!

Comment: When people ask what an LSD run is, I tell them 'run till you hallucinate.'

Comment: DNF = Did Nothing Fatal :)

Comment: Obscure record: AR, or Area Record, e.g. European Record, Asian Record, etc. The "Areas" are formally defined by the IAAF, I think there are six.

Confusing this is the American use of AR to mean American Record.

Comment: VO2 max, technically is a rate not a volume. (And should really be written with a little circle on the V). DNS : Did not start, DQ: disqualified.

Comment: @geoffc You may want to add SB (season best) as well.